# How can I call a function in the part where this comment in the code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, push

I have a question that I searched online but I did not find it.

How can I call a function in the part where this comment in the code?

```
if (drawTile != 0) {
    roomTilesCoordinates.push( {
        Coordinate: (i - j) * tileH / 34 + ',' + (i + j) * tileH / 2 / 17,
        ValueCoordinate: CoordinateTilePositionX + ',' + CoordinateTilePositionY,
        PointsCoordinate: //Call Function and return value
    });
}
```

Comment: If the function is in scope, and it returns the value you want, all you need to do is call it where that comment is.

Comment: But, the question is how to call the function of that part, I tried to normal, but I can not, I get a mistake.

Comment: @ĆarlosOmar Assuming your function is called "testFunction" and is in the same scope, you should be able to call it by typing "testFunction()".

Answer (score 0):

```
PointsCoordinate: yourFunction()
```

Simply, should work...

Answer (score 0):

Try an IIFE, a function that will be executed and return as soon as it is evaluated.

```
f (drawTile != 0) {
    roomTilesCoordinates.push({
        Coordinate: (i - j) * tileH / 34 + ',' + (i + j) * tileH / 2 / 17,
        ValueCoordinate: CoordinateTilePositionX + ',' + CoordinateTilePositionY,
        PointsCoordinate: (function() {
          // some code
        }()) // notice the () invoking the function
    });
}
```

If you're trying to use an existing function just call it... let's say it's named `someFunc`:

```
PointsCoordinate: someFunc()
```